# Are graphs of continuous real-valued functions locally affine varieties?*

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, taylor-expansion, affine-varieties

More specifically, let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R},$ where $n$ is a natural number. Can I use Taylor polynomials to show that if $f$ is continuous (or locally continuous in some neighbourhood) with the Euclidean metric, then its graph is locally an affine variety in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, if the remainder term is identically zero?

Comment: You say "an arbitrary field" and then "the Euclidean metric". That does not seem to go well together.

Comment: I think you're right, I'll edit my question

Comment: A few comments: a locally continuous function is just a continuous function; continuous functions don't have Taylor expansions; and if the remainder term is zero in a Taylor expansion this means the function is just a polynomial.

Comment: Lol you're right I forgot the criterion about differentiability. And I think the second comment answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: @CaptainLama it looks like your comments form an answer to the question. Could you record them as such?

Answer (score 0):

This is a community wiki answer recording the solution from the comments, in order to remove the question from the unanswered queue:

> A few comments: a locally continuous function is just a continuous function; continuous functions don't have Taylor expansions; and if the remainder term is zero in a Taylor expansion this means the function is just a polynomial. – **Captain Lama**